# Attaching listeners in a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dom-events

I have an array of objects (cards) which contain an `id`, `latitude` and `longitude`. I'm then building an array of markers to attach to a GoogleMap map:

```
for(var c = 0; c < cards.length; c++)
{
    var id = cards[c]["id"];
    var lat = cards[c]["lat"];
    var lon = cards[c]["lon"];

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)});
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.addListener('click', function(){
        myListenerCallback(id);
    });
}
```

On each marker I want to attach a callback on the click event. It can be done quite easily by using the marker's `.addListener` method. The problem is, I want to fire a callback which includes the id of the card (as an input parameter): `myListenerCallback(id)`. Looks like all the callbacks are firing using the last id of the array. How can I fire callbacks passing the corresponding id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the event handler will be fired, the loop have finished it's execution and id is update with the last value of the array.

You can create a closure around the event handler function and pass the `id`

```
for (var c = 0; c < cards.length; c++) {
  //rest of the code
  (function(id) {
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      myListenerCallback(id);
    });
  }(id))
}
```

Comment: ok thanks. What are the memory implications of using a closure? What if I rerun the loop over and over? Does the set keeps growing or the functions get overwritten with the new ones (an identical set of course)

Answer (score 1):

```
cards.forEach(function(card){
  var id = card["id"];
  var lat = card["lat"];
  var lon = card["lon"];

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)});
marker.setMap(map);
marker.addListener('click', function(){
    myListenerCallback(id);
});
});
```

See the duplicate post for a description...